# How do I work around dns_get_record returning false positives

Tags: php

I've been trying to use functions like dns_get_record($domain) to check the validity of a domain.  The problem is if it's not a valid domain it appends it on front of the domain for the sites IP that I'm on.  I can't rely on any of the gethostbyname, dns_get_record, etc functions for this as they don't work as I expect them to.

If a domain doesn't exist, I expect any of these functions return a failed result.  Its not.  I notice using the 'ping' command does the same thing as the PHP functions do, but the 'host' command works as expected.

I write a C program to use gethostbyname and it works as expected.  Same with python 'socket.gethostbyname'.  They both fail on a lookup with an invalid domain.

What is going on with the PHP functions?  Why are they not behaving as I expect them too and fail on an invalid domain name?

using the following on a host with the domain name of example.com give the following.

```
dns_get_record('something')

Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [host] => somthing.example.com
                [type] => A
                [ip] => some ip address
                [class] => IN
                [ttl] => 600
            )

    )
```

This is not what I want.  If there is a bug, a link to the bug would be appreciated, thanks

UPDATE:

As correctly pointed out by @Barmar, it's the way the DNS records have been set up.  I found on my home computer, which has PHP on it, the function gethostbyname() and friends work exactly as expected.

This begs the question of how can you reliable check to see if a domain is valid when your DNS is setup to enable wildcards. The only way I found was to use command line tolls and call them from PHP.  I don't like this option, but it's the only one I got at the moment, and it's not a frequently called operation anyway, luckily.

Comment: I suspect if it doesn't loo like an absolute URL, PHP uses it like a relative url (subdomain). You could use a regex or something similar to convert `something` to `something.com` before passing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a wildcard record in your domain. When a name lookup fails, it gets retried with your local domain appended (based on the `domain` or `search` options in `/etc/resolv.conf`). Normally this fails, so the whole lookup fails. But if you have a wildcard in your domain, the retry succeeds, and this gets returned as the result.

Comment: This was what I was going to write, but it doesn't explain the behavior of `gethostbyname`

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like the resolver `ndots` option is being overridden somewhere.

Comment: I'm a little ignorant, what is the ndots option, and why would the php functions do this and not the original C function or the Python sockets method of the same name?

Comment: It's used by the resolver to decide whether to look up a name as is or append domains in the search list. See the `resolv.conf` man page. I'm not sure why it's different in PHP from C/Python.

Comment: It's not quiet the answer I was looking for, but given the way I wrote it, this is good enough, and useful, thanks

Comment: The most reliable method I found, which is what I was trying to avoid, using cmdline through php, is this $query = `nslookup -timeout=$timeout -retry=1 $host`; and check the output with preg_match('/\nAddress: (.*)\n/', $query, $matches). from the online php manual for gethostbyname(), in one of the user comments at the bottom.  I didn't want to do this though

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the automatic search of local domains by appending a period to the domain you're searching for, *e.g:*

```
dns_get_record("something.")
```